# Displaying has_many through association as column in Active Admin index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, has-many-through

How do I display a list of has_many_through associations with the association as the column headings and the through: value as an entry in the table row?

I have 3 models:

```
class Jobs 
  attr_accesor :title 

  has_many :scores 
  has_many :factors, through: :scores 
end 

class Scores 
  attr_accesor :score 

  belongs_to :job 
  belongs_to :factor 
end 

class Factor 
  attr_accesor :name 
  has_many :scores 
  has_many :jobs, through: :scores 
end
```

I want to be able to show, in the Jobs index, a row for each Job, the title of each Factor as a column heading, and the scores of each Job as the value in the cell.

I would expect to have to do something like this in the `app/admin/jobs.rb` file:

```
index do |jobs|
  column :title
  jobs.scores.each do |score|
    column(score.factor.name) { |score| score.score }
  end
end
```

And get output like this:

```
Job              |  Education  |  Experience  |  Leadership  |  ...  |
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
CEO              |     600     |     720      |     580      |  ...  |
Admin Assistant  |     210     |     200      |     150      |  ...  |
```

But activeadmin doesn't seem to like the `jobs.scores.each` line, giving me the following error:

```
undefined method `scores' for 
#<ActiveAdmin::Views::IndexAsTable::IndexTableFor:0x00000104d1dad0>
```

Comment: I think Muhamamd Awais is right, I think you need to change your approach. First make sure you loop through jobs so you have job.scores because it won't know now to find the score unless you're iterating over each individual object. Second, think of it as an erb file. Everything in AA is printed - so when you say job.scores.each it actually printing it out like <%= job.score.each do |score| %> instead of <% job.score.each do |score| %>. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: Thanks Eileen, the second point is new, I didn't think of it that way. The First makes sense, but I haven't been able to figure out how to loop through jobs to get to `job.scores` within the context of the `index` block. ANY help in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your data correctly I think this will work. You can do each all on one line, also if that doesn't work look into map or collect. You can also chain each and map. Ensure 
you're using compact so you don't hit nils. Below I'm assuming the score.factor.name is equal to what each column should be named and what data is filled in.

```
index do |jobs|
  column :title
  column "Education" do |job|
   job.scores.map { |score| score if score.factor.name == "Education"  }.compact
  end
  column "Experience" do |job|
   job.scores.map { |score| score if score.factor.name == "Experience"  }.compact
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks again Eileen, this looks like it might work except that the factor names (`Education` and `Experience`) is what I am trying to figure out the loop on. Essentially i need to pull the names that are associated - they won't be known up front.

Answer (score -1):

see this example for Jobs has_many Scores

```
ActiveAdmin.register Jobs do 
 index do
 :scores do |i|
   table_for i.scores do
     column do |user|
       user.scores
     end
   end
 end
 end
end
```

this is not the exact solution of your problem but it is an overview that how you can do that..!